# Mount SMB/AFP share on network reconnect

Tags: macos, osx-lion, mount, afp, persistence

There's a myriad of possibilities for mounting shares upon Login within OSX. I'm after having it done when a network connection is restored.

Ideally:

- Mount the share
- connection lost
- connection re-gained
- Mount the share again (if possible), otherwise, don't - i.e. different location.

Any idea as to how to make this happen?

Am exploring the possibility using NFS shares from the DroboFS, but would prefer to keep it to CIFS/AFP.

Suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
last_status=0                                                                                  

while :                                                                                        
do                                                                                             
    ping -t 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1                                                      
    exit_status=$?                                                                             

    if [[ $exit_status == 0 && $last_status != 0 ]]; then                                      
        last_status=$exit_status                                                               
        osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' -e 'eject "share"' -e 'end tell'                  
        osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' -e 'open location "smb://server/share"' -e 'end tell'                                                                                      
    else                                                                                       
        last_status=$exit_status                                                               
    fi                                                                                         
    sleep 5                                                                                    
done
```

We check the internet connection by pinging google, you could change that to a local IP if you don't want to test for internet connectivity. If we can ping google then we tell finder to eject the old mount, and mount a the SMB share again, otherwise sleep for 5 seconds.

It's very dirty but it does what you want, there is a lot of room for improvements.